# functor syntax `map` for function does not work?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I can't seem compile this with cats `"org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.0.0-MF"` which was fine with `"org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "0.9.0",`.

```
import cats._
import cats.instances.all._
import cats.syntax.all._

val func1 = (x: Int) => x.toDouble
val func2 = (y: Double) => y * 2
val func3 = func1.map(func2)
func3(3)
```

The error is :

```
Error:(7, 25) value map is not a member of Int => Double
lazy val func3 = func1.map(func2)
                       ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for might just be function composition. You can do:

```
val func3 = func1 andThen func2
```

or

```
val func3 = func2 compose func1
```

However if you want to map over functions you need to have `partial-unification` enabled. 
The easiest way to do so, is to add the `sbt-partial-unification` [plugin](https://github.com/fiadliel/sbt-partial-unification).

If you're on Scala 2.11.9 or newer, you can also simply add the compiler flag:

```
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

With either of those this compiles fine:

```
val func1 = (x: Int) => x.toDouble
val func2 = (y: Double) => y * 2
val func3 = func1.map(func2)
```